# Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process

Tags: maven

I am seeing error Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process.
What can be the root cause of it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as suggested when you signed up today, to get a better idea of what types of questions you can ask. It would be awesome if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I figured out that the problem was with my TestNG xml, a class was misnamed here compare to the original project.